# Using D3, is a force-directed layout the logical way to interpolate node positions?

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, geometry

I'm using D3 to draw a graph. Some nodes have a fixed position, others should automatically take a 'sensible position'. A [sticky force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558) seemed like a logical choice.

However, I'm now thinking a force-directed layout may be overkill for the problem I'm trying to solve, because the non-fixed nodes are always 'internal' nodes; that is, they are always anchored in place by at least two fixed nodes. For example (red = fixed):

[image: internal node position interpolation]

This image was created with a D3 sticky force layout. But a force-directed algorithm actually simulates physical forces. It occurs to me this is probably not needed under these constraints; the position of the gray nodes can probably be determined by a simpler algorithm or equation, though I don't know how.

Is a force-directed layout still the proper solution? Or is there something more efficient available?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about efficiency unless that turns out to be a problem for your application. Using the force layout (i.e. something that already exists) is certainly going to be quicker than implementing a custom layout algorithm.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: I agree in principle. But (1) the graph may contain a great many nodes, depending on the dataset, and (2) I feel like there is probably a standard solution for what I want; I am just not aware of it.

Comment: There's certainly nothing for this implemented in D3.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff: That's very useful information. Thanks!